# DDEV php/twig error "Unknown "link_attributes" filter."

Tags: 8

So I'm trying to setup a local environment with ddev for the first time. I got it running, cloned my live files with git and imported my DB.

Site ain't working and got this in the log : "PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\SyntaxError: "Unknown "link_attributes" filter." at /var/www/html/web/themes/customs/myTheme/templates/menu--main.html.twig

Any pointer how to fix that ? I did :

> ddev exec drush en link_attributes
>
> -> [notice] Already enabled: link_attributes

This site with the same file/db is working on 2 VPS. What's going on ?

Comment: You probably want to install `twig_link_attributes`, see https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_link_attributes

Comment: Yeah I just realized that it's not from the module link_attributes but twig_link_attributes... When I scrolled the module list, I saw link_attributes and checked it was enabled and downloaded. Damn filter named the same as another module D: 

Thx mate !

** It din't download cause it's a git submodule... Gonna fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an module identification problem. I thought it was the link_attributes modules but the error is from twig_link_attributes. That one didn't download cause it's a git submodule or something... Anyway that folder is empty.